# Error when get value in <ul><li>

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="heading">
<ul>
<li id="one">One</li>
<li id="two">Two</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I using this jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.heading ul li').click(function(){
        var type1 = $('#one').val();
        var type2 = $('#two').val();
        if(type1) {
            alert("1");
        } else {
            alert("2");
        }
    });    
});
</script>
```

=> Error when click on One or Two, result is 2, too , how to fix it ?

Comment: You might need text() to get either "one" or "two".

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by if(type1)? I think you want to check if the value of the li is one then enter the if statement? Then you should:

```
  $('.heading ul li').click(function(){
    var type1 = $('#one').html();
    var type2 = $('#two').html();
    if($(this).val() == type1) {
        alert("1");
    } else {
        alert("2");
    }
});
```

Hope this help :)

(Edited from val to html)

Comment: The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea-http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.val()` it returns a string. Any string other than `0` will return as `true` in your if statement. But you have more problems. `val` gives you the value of an input. List items do not have a value property so this won't work. You probably want to retrieve the html instead.

```
$('li').click( function() {
  var type1 = $('#one').html();
  var type2 = $('#two').html();

  if (type1 == 'One') { ... }
  else { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.4, the .text() method returns the value of text and CDATA nodes as well as element nodes.

here is the link for jquery text()
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Try

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){     
    $('.heading ul li').click(function(){         
    var type1 = $('#one').text();         
    var type2 = $('#two').text();         
    if(type1 =="One") {             
       alert("1");         
    } else {
       alert("2");        
    }     
    });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why in the world does the guy who answers the question correctly get a downvote and the guy that answers it wrong get an upvote? Anyways, +1 from me.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Did not notice -ve voting. Thank you so much for upvote.

Comment: My downvote, debated it, subtle, but there's no reason to put that test in a click handler unless he wanted to test against the item clicked. Reading into the question, seems he really wants to test `if ($(this).text() === type1)...`

Comment: @steveax:Thanks for explanation regarding downvoting but wondering for the reason behind downvoting.There should be some policy for downvoting.

Comment: @steveax - how can you assume that the OP doesn't need it in a click handler? You shouldn't downvote based on assumptions. Hoque's answer is correct in that he correctly identified and fixed OP's code. If OP made a poor code choice (debatable in this case) then it isn't Hoque's fault.

Comment: Point taken. Tried to remove downvote but alas it is locked now unless the answer is edited.